# esp8266 send json request body in lua

Tags: php, json, lua, esp8266

I am very new to lua and I am trying to send a json post from my ESP8266 using lua to a PHP server on my localhost, I searched the internet and I can't find any example to do that can any one help me please ?

My lua code

```lua
-- tested on NodeMCU 0.9.5 build 20141222...20150108
-- sends connection time and heap size to http:server.php
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("VIVA-4G-LTE-6134","VIVA176429")
--wifi.sta.config("AndroidAP","rapz4736")

print('httpget.lua started')
Tstart  = tmr.now()

conn = nil
conn = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0) 

-- show the retrieved web page

conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload) 
                       success = true
                       print(payload) 
                       end) 

-- once connected, request page (send parameters to a php script)

conn:on("connection", function(conn, payload) 
                       print('\nConnected') 
                       conn:send("POST /server.php?"
                        .."name=mometto"
                        .."&age=27"
                        .." HTTP/1.1\r\n" 
                        .."Host: 172.0.0.1\r\n" 
                        .."Connection: close\r\n"
                        .."Accept: */*\r\n" 
                        .."User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 "
                        .."(compatible; esp8266 Lua; "
                        .."Windows NT 5.1)\r\n" 
                        .."\r\n") 
                   --  conn:send("what":"books", "count":3 )
                       end) 

-- when disconnected, let it be known
conn:on("disconnection", function(conn, payload) print('\nDisconnected') end)

conn:connect(80,'192.168.43.181')
```

here it is easy for me to send parameters, but when i want to send a request body i cant, i tried to add this code to send the request body

```lua
conn:send("what":"books", "count":3 )
```

but it is not working and i get this message:

> [image]

so can any one provide any help for me please?

Comment: `conn:send('"what":"books", "count":3')`